Variable ___ might not have been initialized
I just started learning Java for my programming class and I have to create a decimal to binary calculator where it loops until the user inputs "stop", I'm having trouble with needing a different variable type to for the user to input and stop the program.
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            {

                    //created integer variables for the remainders and an array for binary numbers
                    int remainder, decNumber, i = 1, j;
                    int binaryNumber[] = new int[100];

                    //scanner to take user input
                    Scanner myCalc = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("Enter a decimal number: ");
                    String decimalNumber = myCalc.nextLine();


                if (decimalNumber == "STOP")
                    {
                        System. exit(0);
                    } else
                    {
                        decNumber = Integer.parseInt(decimalNumber);
                    }
                
                    remainder = decNumber;

                    //While loop converts the decimal to binary
                    while (remainder != 0)
                    {
                        binaryNumber[i++] = remainder % 2;
                        remainder = remainder / 2;
                    }

                    //Output is shown using the print method
                    System.out.println("This Binary number is ");
                    for (j = i - 1; j > 0; j--)
                    {
                        System.out.print(binaryNumber[j]);
                    }


            }
    }

}

I tried converting the input into an integer if the user types "stop" but it didn't work at all.

Please be mor specific than "didn't work at all", and explain how this relates to the title of you post.

Where do you think decNumber has been initialized?

Notes: 1) never use == to compare Strings (or Objects), use equals like in if (decimalNumber.equals("STOP")). 2) the compiler does not know that System.exit() will stop the code; it assumes that the code will eventually continue running after its call, as with any other method
